# Unable to Set Javascript Indent on Spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, javascript

I have a vanilla Spacemacs setup, and in my `.spacemacs` file, the `dotspacemacs/user-config` definition I have added `(setq js2-basic-offset 2)` which should be sufficient to set the indent length as `2`. I have also placed this before in my `user-init` with no luck as well.

I can verify this in my window using `SPC h d v` which it shows to be `2`.

Yet, in my `.js` files it continues to indent 4 spaces. My spacemacs shows "Javascript" for the major mode in the modeline bar.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong/how I can debug this?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I needed `js-indent-level` because I was in `js-mode`. Still unsure how I ended up in `js-mode` and not `js2-mode`.

Comment: Can you accept your own answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see the option..

Comment: @AdamThompson There is usually an interval that must elapse before you can accept your own question (this is to prevent abusing the SE format to 'juice' your points). You should be able to accept it now.